# Is the way to disable path shortening in windows TaskDialogs (c#)?

Tags: c#, taskdialog

I've used WindowsApiCodePack C# wrapper of windows TaskDialogs.
When I tried to show long text with paths, I got all my paths shortened by ellipsis instead of true word-wrap. This makes filenames in paths non-readable. Like here:

[image: TaskDialog screenshow] 
Same behavior when settings this text in spolier text or in main text.

Is the way to disable this feature? I want my paths to be shown completely, wrapped or somehow else.

This is what I expect from text. How MessageBox work with text:
[image: MessageBox]

Comment: AFAIK you can't disable that, but it's a *feature* mind you. Just use CTRL+C on the dialog and you should get the full text in the clipboard.

Comment: thanks, it works. Never knew that this thing supports clipboard.. but i think the dialog should show info by itself and don't force to use another window (notepad) to read its content

Comment: The TaskDialog is arguably *not* meant for such kind of usage. If you have a big block of text you probably should build a dedicated window with a scrollbar. The goal here is to ensure the dialog won't get larger than the screen, which is a confusing user experience.

Comment: old style MessageBoxes were good enough for this:) And no. TaskDialog have a *width* setting, that allows to set width of window in some units (not pixels, symbols may be). And it will never be larger than screen. More than this, why such strange shortening? Why not just word wrap, like 100% of other dialogs do?

Comment: I guess your path simply does not contain any space, so you can't really *word wrap*, look: it wrapped after the word `line`

Comment: Yep, seems so Any wordwrap mechanism breaks by character in this conditions. This thing shortens the path before space (and hides filename) and then wraps